# Php: How to protect images for downloading

Tags: php, codeigniter

In my site we are doing image protecting section. Can I protect images in my site from others without download.That is i want to protect my image from downloading by others.Is it possible using php code

Comment: Please search this site first you will get several posts on this.

Comment: you can disable JavaScript to right-click. There is no good alternative solution: If you know the URL to the image, you can download it

Answer (score 0):

you can do this by using force download in php.

```
$file_url = 'base path to file / file name';
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: Binary"); 
header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=\"" . basename($file_url) . "\""); 
readfile($file_url);
```

this code will download the file and block files folder using htaccess

```
<IfModule authz_core_module>
   Require all denied
</IfModule>

<IfModule !authz_core_module>
   Deny from all
</IfModule>
```